# Cannot parse "1,000.00" String to Number

Tags: java

I have several labels displaying numeric values and I need to parse these texts to number. The problem is that when the value is greater than 999, the parse method fails throwing the following exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,000.00" at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

I tried several parse methods like `Double.valueOf(string)`, new `BigDecimal(string)`, `new BigInteger(string)` and so on...but the exception is always thrown.

Comment: remove the comma before parsing like this: `Double.parseDouble(string.replace(',',''))`

Comment: You have to remove the comma character. Java computes the decimal based on the period character, but thousands etc are not grouped by a delimiter

Comment: That was so easy. I should've figured it out. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: To bee strict: different countries have different decimal point (Poland, Germany comma) and thousands separator can be comma, dot or space. In real life we polish programmers (in strictly polish software) use method like in answers, but remember they are not portable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are using a French numbers. 
You can [add a Locale to NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) and [parse in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) :

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("1,000")
```

Comment: This is a clean way of doing it. +1

Comment: Just a note: one can use `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()` to use the systems default locale. If this should be used, then there is no need to pass it explicitly.

Comment: I'm not using French numbers but the result is the same. I think I'll create an interface for having both `format` and `parse` methods, based on the same custom `DecimalFormat`. This, at least, should be portable. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: These aren't French numbers. French notation requires thousands to be separated by a space, and decimals are split from units by a comma.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the comma before parsing like this:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(string.replace(",", ""));
```